# ios - Can't add custom fonts on my application

Tags: ios

I have a problem with customs fonts in xcode, I try import 6 or 7 different fonts, but I always see this:[image: ?]

On finder, i see the fonts normally, but on xcode I see this, and on Emulator I see any "[?]":

[image: "?"]

Anybody can fix this?

Comment: What does it look like in `/Applications/Font Book`?

Comment: The fonts are normal...

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was my project name contained specials caracters and I think him lost the path to the font.